# RadGrid bug on filtering with EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

wherever I try to filter a bounded column with RadGrid I get the following error:

"Could not resolve 'COLUMN NAME' in scope or current context. Check that all referenced variables are in scope, if required schemes were loaded and references to namespaces are correct. Next simple identifier, line 6, column 3."

My page's code is:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VerOcorrencias.aspx.cs" Inherits="DuctorWebSite.OuvidoriaPages.VerOcorrencias" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>

    <link href="../Content/OuvidoriaPages.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="container-full">
        <h2>Lista de ocorrências</h2>

        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1"
            RenderMode="Auto" Culture="pt-BR" Skin="Metro"
            AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand" EnableLinqExpressions="False" GroupPanelPosition="Top">

            <ExportSettings>
                <Pdf PageWidth="">
                </Pdf>
            </ExportSettings>

            <MasterTableView DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" DataKeyNames="OUV_Id" PageSize="25">

                <EditFormSettings>
                    <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" CancelText="Cancelar" EditText="Editar" UpdateText="Confirmar" ButtonType="ImageButton" CancelImageUrl="../Images/icons/cancelar.png"
                        UpdateImageUrl="../Images/icons/ok.png">
                    </EditColumn>
                </EditFormSettings>

                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Editar" Text="Editar resposta" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="../Images/icons/editar.png" Resizable="False">
                        <ItemStyle Width="41px" />
                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>

                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Apagar mensagem inteira" UniqueName="DeleteColumn" ConfirmText="Você tem certeza que quer apagar essa mensagem?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ConfirmDialogHeight="25px" HeaderStyle-Width="15px" ItemStyle-Width="15px"
                        ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="../Images/icons/apagar.png">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="15px" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="41px" />
                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_Id" DataType="System.Int32" Display="False" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Id column" HeaderText="OUV_Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="OUV_Id" UniqueName="OUV_Id" Visible="False" Resizable="False">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <ItemStyle Width="41px" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_DtdRegistro" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_DtdRegistro column" HeaderText="&lt;b&gt;DATA REGISTRO&lt;/b&gt;" SortExpression="OUV_DtdRegistro" UniqueName="OUV_DtdRegistro" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" Resizable="False">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_Protocolo" DataType="System.Double" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Protocolo column" HeaderText="&lt;b&gt;PROTOCOLO&lt;/b&gt;" SortExpression="OUV_Protocolo" UniqueName="OUV_Protocolo" ReadOnly="True" Resizable="False">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridCalculatedColumn DataFields="OUV_Nome,OUV_Email,OUV_Telefone" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" UniqueName="column" Expression="OUV_Nome + '<br/>' + OUV_Email + '<br/>' + OUV_Telefone" HeaderText="&lt;b&gt;IDENTIFICAÇÃO&lt;/b&gt;" Resizable="False">
                        <FooterStyle Width="100px" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                    </telerik:GridCalculatedColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_Mensagem" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Mensagem column" HeaderText="&lt;b&gt;MENSAGEM&lt;/b&gt;" SortExpression="OUV_Mensagem" UniqueName="OUV_Mensagem" ReadOnly="True" Resizable="False" MaxLength="150">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <FooterStyle Width="500px" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="250px" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_DtdResposta" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_DtdResposta column" HeaderText="&lt;b&gt;DATA RESPOSTA&lt;/b&gt;" SortExpression="OUV_DtdResposta" UniqueName="OUV_DtdResposta" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" Resizable="False">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_Resposta" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Resposta column" HeaderText="&lt;b&gt;RESPOSTA&lt;/b&gt;" SortExpression="OUV_Resposta" UniqueName="OUV_Resposta" Resizable="False" MaxLength="150">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        <ItemStyle Width="250px" Wrap="True" />
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_Nome" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Nome column" HeaderText="OUV_Nome" SortExpression="OUV_Nome" UniqueName="OUV_Nome" Display="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_Email" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Email column" HeaderText="OUV_Email" SortExpression="OUV_Email" UniqueName="OUV_Email" Display="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_Telefone" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Telefone column" HeaderText="OUV_Telefone" SortExpression="OUV_Telefone" UniqueName="OUV_Telefone" Display="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_ChaveLoc" Display="False" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_ChaveLoc column" HeaderText="OUV_ChaveLoc" SortExpression="OUV_ChaveLoc" UniqueName="OUV_ChaveLoc" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="OUV_Ativo" DataType="System.Boolean" Display="False" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_Ativo column" HeaderText="OUV_Ativo" SortExpression="OUV_Ativo" UniqueName="OUV_Ativo" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="OUV_idCAT" Display="False" FilterControlAltText="Filter OUV_idCAT column" HeaderText="OUV_idCAT" SortExpression="OUV_idCAT" UniqueName="OUV_idCAT" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CAT_Descr" Display="False" FilterControlAltText="Filter CAT_Descr column" HeaderText="CAT_Descr" SortExpression="CAT_Descr" UniqueName="CAT_Descr" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings>
                            <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle Position="TopAndBottom" />
            </MasterTableView>


            <FilterMenu RenderMode="Mobile">
            </FilterMenu>
            <HeaderContextMenu RenderMode="Mobile">
            </HeaderContextMenu>

        </telerik:RadGrid>

    </div>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=DuctorWebSiteEntities"
        DefaultContainerName="DuctorWebSiteEntities" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Ouvidoria" OrderBy="it.OUV_DtdRegistro Desc" EntityTypeFilter="Ouvidoria">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

I need some help, thanks.